# Dynamically change end date format based on current day

Tags: php, datetime

I am putting together a membership site that uses a pro rata system for memberships fees.

EG

***$75.00 from 01 Apr YY - 31 Mar YY*** but if you join at say around Sep YY, then you only pay the pro rata of $38.00

My current coding is working fine - no probs.

But was wondering is there a way to to dynamically change the end date ($your_date) below so I don't have to manually edit it every 12 months?

So for instance, if today's date was 01 Feb 2017, then $your_date below is correct.

However, if todays date was 14 May 2017, then $your_date below of course is incorrect.

Membership year runs from 01 Apr this/last year - 31 Mar this/next year, so it would be

if Today's date <= 31 Mar this/next year && >= 01 Apr this/last year then do something..

```html
 <?php
     $now = time(); // or your date as well
     $your_date = strtotime("2017-03-31");
     $datediff = $your_date - $now;
     $SOS = floor($datediff/(60*60*24)*0.205);
     $ORD = floor($datediff/(60*60*24)*0.115);
     $GEN = floor($datediff/(60*60*24)*0.03);

?>
```

Or have I got a fixation with the code I'm using and there is something a lot simpler?

Comment: `$your_date` will always be **next** year-03-31 ?

Comment: So, will it be ... `$your_date = strtotime(date('Y') . "-03-31");` ?

Comment: Adding one year to `date('Y')` @Raptor

Comment: ...which doesn't work if the current date is between Jan 1 and Mar 30

Comment: oh yes @Jorge, was typing too fast. `$your_date = strtotime(((int)date('Y')+1) . "-03-31");`

Comment: Hi @Jorge.  Can you explain in laymans terms how this coding works? I have been trying to research the (int) bit, but nothing really answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP below is deliberately verbose in order that each line explains itself:

```
$Current_Year = date('Y');
$Current_Month = date('n');
$Current_Day = date('j');

$Next_Year = ($Current_Year + 1);

if ($Current_Month < 4) {
$Expiration_Year = $Current_Year;
}

if ($Current_Month > 3) {
$Expiration_Year = $Next_Year;
}

# Checks if date is March 31st
if (($Current_Month == 3) && ($Current_Day == 31)) {
$Expiration_Year = $Next_Year;
}

$Expiration_Date = $Expiration_Year.'-03-31';
```

Comment: Thanks guys.Much appreciated.

Comment: Thx Rounin
Will give this a bash and see what happens.  Should be OK if someone applies on the 31 Mar YY?

Comment: Good question. I have added a special check at the bottom to handle the March 31st Application case.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little complicated, but I think you want:

> If the current date is April or later, then March 31 *next* year, otherwise it's March 31 *this* year.

Does that about sum it up? Of course, if they're applying **on** the 31st of March, that'd be a $0.00 fee...

So I think the code should be:

```
$your_year = ( date('m')>'3' ? ((int)date('Y')+1) : date('Y') )
$your_date = strtotime( $your_year . "-03-31" )
```